# Crash - Booted out of app to Apple logo screen (Crash restarted iPad)

Tags: crash, reboot

I have been getting these random crashes with my app. I am running it in debug or release mode and it boots me out of the app and sends me straight to the black apple screen and not to the Springboard screen.

I am using a fair bit of core animations with CAAnimationGroup's and using AVAudioPlayer for sounds

Here is the crash log that was displayed in the Device Logs of the organiser window.

```
Aug 16 17:06:53 unknown HRG[86] <Warning>: -[CAETimelineObjectSound     audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:] Audio "snd_01_01.caf" play finished;     successfully=1
Aug 16 17:06:54 unknown ReportCrash[88] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process SpringBoard[27]
Aug 16 17:06:54 unknown ReportCrash[88] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/SpringBoard_2011-08-16-170654_Test-iPad-2.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
Aug 16 17:06:54 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.COMPANY.AppName[0x4e02]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3794 (24506):3
Aug 16 17:06:54 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.COMPANY.AppName[0x4e02]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3202 (24506):10
Aug 16 17:06:54 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.COMPANY.AppName[0x4e02]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed.
Aug 16 17:06:54 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.COMPANY.AppName[0x4e02]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Aug 16 17:06:54 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[85] <Warning>: 1 [0055/1503]: error: ::read ( 4, 0x2ff879f0, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.SpringBoard) Job appears to have crashed: Bus error: 10
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: virtual void AppleRGBOUT::do_power_state_change(): fSoft: 1 fHard: 1 swapBusy: 0  fController: 0 -> 1
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: bool AppleRGBOUT::power_up_hardware()
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: set_crc_notification_state 0
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: virtual void AppleRGBOUT::do_power_state_change(): fSoft: 0 fHard: 1 swapBusy: 0  fController: 1 -> 0
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: bool AppleRGBOUT::power_down_hardware()
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: bool AppleRGBOUT::power_down_hardware(), clock down RGBOUT
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: bool AppleRGBOUT::power_down_hardware(), RGB_CTRL (0x00000000) clk_down_ready is not set after 60 msecs
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: IOReturn AppleRGBOUT::set_display_device_gated(uint32_t), 1
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: virtual void AppleRGBOUT::do_power_state_change(): fSoft: 1 fHard: 1 swapBusy: 1  fController: 0 -> 1
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: bool AppleRGBOUT::power_up_hardware()
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: set_crc_notification_state 0
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: virtual void AppleRGBOUT::do_power_state_change(): fSoft: 0 fHard: 1 swapBusy: 0  fController: 1 -> 0
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: IOReturn IOMobileFramebufferUserClient::set_hotplug_notify(void*, void*) 0x30b6d911 0x201642b0
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: IOReturn IOMobileFramebufferUserClient::set_hotplug_notify(void*, void*) 0x8bed3c00 0x8a3de06c 0x30b6d911 0x201642b0
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Warning>: No AppleBaseband service detected. Cellular data disabled.
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Error>: WiFi: Consulting "no-sdio-devices" property.
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Error>: WiFi: "no-sdio-devices" property not found.
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Notice>: CLTM: initial thermal level is 0
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Notice>: MultitouchHID(1f5694f0) uilock state: 1 -> 0
Aug 16 17:06:55 unknown locationd[22] <Error>: hidd died. Reestablishing connection.
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: bool AppleRGBOUT::power_down_hardware()
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: bool AppleRGBOUT::power_down_hardware(), clock down RGBOUT
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: bool AppleRGBOUT::power_down_hardware(), RGB_CTRL (0x00000000) clk_down_ready is not set after 60 msecs
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Warning>: lockdown says the device is: [Activated], state is 3
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Notice>: port forwarding is allowed
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Info>: checking for carrier provisioning
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Info>: carrier service is not available
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Debug>: published changes: success
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Info>: maximum number of wireless tethered hosts is 3
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Debug>: published changes: success
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Debug>: attached to SpringBoard (0x1f666cc0, port 0x3c0b)
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Debug>: detached from SpringBoard (0x1f666cc0, port 0x1f666d00)
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Debug>: no clients left; resuming idle timer
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Warning>: BTM: attaching to BTServer
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Debug>: spd:_libspd_initialize_protocol:142 Registered notification port with spd [PID=93]
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Debug>: spd:_libspd_initialize_notify:241 All set up for spd wake notifications
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Debug>: attached to SpringBoard (0x1f666d60, port 0x400b)
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Debug>: detached from SpringBoard (0x1f666d60, port 0x1f666da0)
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown misd[92] <Debug>: no clients left; resuming idle timer
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Error>: mms: ***** isMmsConfigured = 0
Aug 16 17:06:56 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Warning>: BTM: posting notification BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification
Aug 16 17:06:57 unknown com.apple.printd[94] <Notice>: Accepted connection from localhost:631 (Domain)
Aug 16 17:06:57 unknown com.apple.printd[94] <Notice>: Closing connection from localhost:631 (Domain)
Aug 16 17:06:57 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Error>: WiFi: Consulting "no-sdio-devices" property.
Aug 16 17:06:57 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Error>: WiFi: "no-sdio-devices" property not found.
Aug 16 17:06:57 unknown com.apple.printd[94] <Notice>: Accepted connection from localhost:631 (Domain)
Aug 16 17:06:57 unknown com.apple.printd[94] <Notice>: Closing connection from localhost:631 (Domain)
Aug 16 17:07:04 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Notice>: MultitouchHID(1f5694f0) uilock state: 0 -> 1
Aug 16 17:07:16 unknown SpringBoard[89] <Debug>: spd:___libspd_initialize_protocol_block_invoke_2:172 spd [PID=93] went bye-bye
Aug 16 17:07:56 unknown misd[92] <Debug>: now quitting (60 sec idle)
Aug 16 17:07:56 unknown misd[92] <Info>: exit: 0
```

There are no other logs saved on to my computer or on the device.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you checked the file /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/SpringBoard_2011-08-16-170654_Test-iPad-2.plist?